# How to DROP TABLE with python odbc on SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am using the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and pyodbc. The following code does not work.

```
cursor.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?""", "table_name")
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Tablenames cannot be parameters in general...wouldn't expect that to work in Python....doesn't work in SQL server t sql

Comment: So how can I drop a variable table without being susceptible to SQL injection? String formatting is not the way to go.

Comment: @HarryTouloupas I might be wrong but you seems to have an extra `"` in `"""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?""""`.

Comment: You can always write a proc and check if the tablenames car is in the system catalog before execution of the command as a way to check it's validity

Comment: @scharette No everything is fine.

Comment: check this: cursor.execute ("drop table if exists %s" % mdb.escape_string(table_name))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility might be to use an anonymous code block that employs the [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to ensure that the string you pass is treated as a complete table name:

```python
# this table name could be problematic if QUOTENAME wasn't used
tbl_name = "]; TRUNCATE TABLE Customer; --"

sql = """\
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @drop NVARCHAR(max);
SET @drop = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + QUOTENAME(?);
EXEC sp_executesql @drop;
"""
crsr.execute(sql, tbl_name)
```

Comment: This seems correct. Is this immune to SQL injection because of QUOTENAME?